# Lightroom upgrade from a student licence

Tags: lightroom

I am thinking of buying Adobe Lightroom through a student licence.

Will I be able to buy an upgrade licence when I'm not longer a student?

Or will I have to buy the full licence?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, I bought Lightroom  as a student and I have been upgrading since version 1.0 without a problem.